# Synonym proposal: [model-view-presenter] -> [mvp]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Most questions are tagged as [mvp](/questions/tagged/mvp). So I think the [model-view-presenter](/questions/tagged/model-view-presenter) tag could be the synonym.  I would have proposed it through the usual UI but I don't have the necessary rep.

Note: Something similar already exists for [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvc/synonyms) (ie [model-view-controller](/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) -> [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc))

Comment: @Harvey - Can I get the badge for this? :)